# Connect to SQL Server 2005 remotely

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I installed SQL Server 2005 Express on a remote machine and I can connect to that with `machinename\sqlexpress` locally.

But I can't connect to that engine remotely.

I did these steps, but the problem still exists:

1. Turned off firewall on both sides
2. Enabled tcpip protocol and set tcp port (IPALL) to 1433 and disabled 'Listen All' (because if TCP is enabled and 'Listen All' is enabled at the same time, SQL Server engine is going to stop and I have to disable Listen All in order to start engine)
3. server allow for remote connection box is checked
4. Ensured that SQL Browser is started
5. I use mix mode authentication

and also when I try to connect to engine I see packets in Wireshark with dst port=1434 that belong to the SQL Browser service.

At the end I can't connect to the SQL Server engine locally with this server name:

```
127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS
```

but

```
machinename\sqlexpress
```

or

```
.\sqlexpress
```

are OK.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: do a google search on how to connect to sql server 2005 express remotely also why are you installing such an antiquated ver of Sql Server..?

Comment: i use sql server2005 to sure that my app can work with all of sql server engine , I search google but find nothing more than I said above

Comment: I was under the impression the whole point of SQL Express is that it was local only

Comment: This page for example says "local data stores" https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21844

Comment: Hogan, i think you might be mistaken , actually can connect sqlexpress remotely

Comment: so why it has configuration for tcp ip ? do you think if i use upper version of sqlexpress my problem will solve?

Comment: sql express 2005 is antiquated and your argument of working with all versions doesn't really work. There are a lot of versions older than 2005. So many features are not available using 2005. Since this sounds like new development you should consider a newer version.

Comment: dear sean lange and Hogan , do you think cant connect to sqlexpress2005 remotely?

Comment: I think you might be mistaken, you are the one asking the question.  Why in the world do you think a product given away as a local dev tool as a spring board to the full product allow remote connections?  What makes you think it is possible to do this.  You are wrong.

Comment: @Hogan: I can confirm from my own experience -- on live production servers that are in operation at this very minute -- that SQL Server Express, in various versions from 2005 to 2012, **is** capable of being configured to accept remote connections.

Comment: @RossPresser -- wait a second... we are talking about 2005.  In 2008 and later they changed their policy.  Really you have a 2005 Express with remote access?  :)

Comment: Hmm.  I was about to provide [this](http://screencast.com/t/WvIyLinfy) as proof ... but you're right, it's 2008 R2, not 2005. Let me look at my other servers ... perhaps I don't have a 2005 left in operation.

Comment: Nope, I do not have any 2005 left in operation. I remember it being enabled, but I'm not sure I can trust that memory now. :(

Comment: However, [this link](http://www.datamasker.com/SSE2005_NetworkCfg.htm) says it is possible and gives instructions.

Comment: dear @Hogan , now I install sqlExpress 2012 but problem still exist .

Comment: I  think  there is need to special tcp config.

Answer (score 1):

The point of the 2005 product was to be local.  I remember, I was there.

@RossPresser provided a link in the comments that will "enable" remote access.  In this case they are getting around the intention of the product and probably breaking the licensing agreement.  They are also using tools that are not included in the 2005 Express package but in the enterprise products.

Microsoft has since changed their policy and now provides free products that include remote access and remote tools.

The OP should just use these newer products -- there is no need to use 2005 remotely and is probably a HUGE security risk to do so once you break/root the product to enable remote access.

Just use any Express product since 2005 -- it will work turn-key.

Comment: I install sqlexpress 2012 but problem still exist

Comment: as I mentioned I disabled 'Listen All'. can it is be origin of problem?

Comment: my connectionstring for default instance is : "Server=192.168.74.128;Database=TaminDB; User Id=Tamin; password= 123456 ;Asynchronous Processing=true;Connect Timeout=2"

Comment: I also try this "Server=192.168.74.128,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Database=TaminDB; User Id=Tamin; password= 123456 ;Asynchronous Processing=true;Connect Timeout=2"

Comment: I question both of these ->Asynchronous Processing=true;Connect Timeout=2  Why do you think they make sense?

Comment: I use Asynchronous Processing=true;Connect Timeout=2 in locally connection string and this is work locally. meanwhile now I remove those and I cant connect remotely again but it takes more time to reject the connection.